# Howcome my accordion is not collapsing? - identical one does work

Tags: angularjs, accordion

http://plnkr.co/edit/xUuZyQTES83yccFRcc4K?p=preview

Check out my plunker that replicates my exact problem. I trimmed my code as much as I could.

I've also skimmed my code as much as I can.. and unfortunately I have not been able to find what is so significantly different between the first set of accordions and the second that is causing the first set to not work.

First set(not working):

```
        <div ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" class="{{x.count}}Details">
          <li class="m2Details m3Details"><a data-toggle="collapse" dataTarget="#{{x.count}}toggleBuilding" href="#">Building<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
          <ul id="{{x.count}}toggleBuilding" class="accordion-body {{x.buildingOpen}}">
              <li ng-repeat="y in this[x.count + 'InfoBuilding']" class="{{y.linkclass}}"><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" class="{{x.count}}Details">
          <li class="m2Details m3Details m4Details"><a data-toggle="collapse" dataTarget="#{{x.count}}toggleOffsite" href="#">Offsite<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
          <ul id="{{x.count}}toggleOffsite" class="accordion-body {{x.offsiteOpen}}">
              <li ng-repeat="y in this[x.count + 'InfoOffsite']" class="{{y.linkclass}}"><a href="{{y.link}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><img src="{{y.icon}}" width="15px" height="15px">{{y.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

This code is wrapped in another ul tag and additional stuff within..but I doubt any of that is having an affect since it is all functioning fine otherwise but here is a skeleton replica:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><img></li>
  <li ng-repeat=""><a>{{text}}</a></li>
  <li><a><span>Text</a></li>
     ///first set of code (above)
 </ul>
</div>
```

Second set(working):

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" class="buildingDropdown {{x.count}}Details {{locationsVisibility}}">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="toggleHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{x.count}}LocationsList" href="#"><span>Locations</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul id="{{x.count}}LocationsList" class="accordion-body collapse buildingListDropdown">
          <a ng-repeat="y in this[x.count + 'InfoBuilding']" href="{{y.link}}" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><li>{{y.name}}</li></a>
          <a ng-repeat="y in this[x.count + 'InfoOffsite']" href="{{y.link}}" class="{{y.linkclass}}" ng-click="clickLinks(y.initialOut,y.initialIn,y.backIn,y.backOut,y.name)"><li>{{y.name}}</li></a>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Anyone care to take a look? It's probably something small and embarrassing, like a "DOH!" moment. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: this will help you https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - it's something small!

You have accidentally camel cased some of the `data-target` attributes:

```
<li class="m2Details m3Details">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" dataTarget="#{{x.count}}toggleBuilding" href="#">
    Building
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Note `dataTarget` should be `data-target`.

Comment: I thought it was a fairly well used thing! After reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase it turns out there are quite a few different names. Maybe I'll call it wimpyCaps from now on.